# What would be the combined dielectric constant of two dielectrics in series?

Tags: capacitance, dielectric

Let's say we have two parallel conductor plates. In the middle, there is not one but two layers of dielectrics made of different materials. If we know the relative permittivity of each dielectric, how could we couple it to get a single dielectric constant?

Comment: You would need to know the relative thicknesses of the two materials.  Dielectric constants are in Farad/Meter (using a cubical model like resistivity), so you can substitute the thickness to get F/M^2.  Then the combination is essentially two caps in series, and you can derive resultant F/M for your sheet.

Comment: Let's say the thicknesses are known. Would it really be two capacitors in series? Because there are two conductor plates, not three or four if that makes sense. The dielectrics are also acting together instead of 'in series'. But it may be the same thing, I am not sure.

Comment: If you put an intermediate, infinitely thin conducting plate at the junction of the two dielectrics, it would be literally and physically two capacitors in parallel.  However, except for negligible fringing effects, the field structure would be identical--hence equivalent.